# Как при разных значениях размера окон, а также при ресайзе без обновления страницы изменять загружаемый скрипт?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ссылка на jsfiddle : [CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/66r7jpw6/)

```js
if ( $(window).width() > 600) {
  $('.show_xs a').click(function(){
    $('.first_p').fadeToggle();
  });
}else if ( $(window).width() < 600) {
  $('.show_xs a').click(function(){
    $('.first_p').slideToggle();
  });
}
```

```css
.first_p{
  display: none;
}
a{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show_xs">
  <a href="#">Toggle text</a>
    
</div>
<div class="first_p">Do you feel cold and lost in desperation? You build up hope but failure is all you know? Remember all the sadness and frustration and let it go, let it go</div>
```

Проблема при ресайзе окна. При первичной загрузке страницы, загружается нужный скрипт, но при ресайзе(при переходе с мобильной версии на десктопный) окна без обновлении страницы не загружается скрипт для данной ширины экрана, т.е. первый загруженный скрипт не изменяется.

Answer (score 1):

А каким образом по вашему должен отработать скрипт, если он у вас 1 раз отрабатывает при загрузке и всё.

Вам событие resize надо прикрутить чтоб отслеживать изменение разрешения экрана.

```js
$( window ).resize(function() { 
if ( $(window).width() > 600) {
console.log('work > 600');
  $('.show_xs a').click(function(){
$('.first_p').fadeToggle();

  });
}else if ( $(window).width() < 600) {
console.log('work < 600');
 $('.show_xs a').click(function(){
$('.first_p').slideToggle();

  });
}
} )

if ( $(window).width() > 600) {
console.log('work > 600');
  $('.show_xs a').click(function(){
$('.first_p').fadeToggle();

  });
}else if ( $(window).width() < 600) {
console.log('work < 600');
 $('.show_xs a').click(function(){
$('.first_p').slideToggle();

  });
}
```

```css
.first_p{
  display: none;
}
a{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show_xs">
  <a href="#">Toggle text</a>
    
</div>
<div class="first_p">Do you feel cold and lost in desperation? You build up hope but failure is all you know? Remember all the sadness and frustration and let it go, let it go</div>
```